# Laravel S3 file upload - The PutObject operation requires non-empty parameter: Bucket

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload file to Amazon S3, but still got an error.

> local.ERROR: The PutObject operation requires non-empty parameter: Bucket {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The PutObject operation requires non-empty parameter: Bucket at /usr/share/nginx/html/PaymentCloud-API/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/InputValidationMiddleware.php:64)

I looked at all posts related to this in stackoverflow and github.
This is the way I used to upload file.

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('filename', 'content')
```

I checked content and I received it successfully.
I checked s3 configuration in .env and filesystems.php, but they are all fine.

Comment: This is the error I got. - local.ERROR: The PutObject operation requires non-empty parameter: Bucket {"exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): The PutObject operation requires non-empty parameter: Bucket at /usr/share/nginx/html/PaymentCloud-API/vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/InputValidationMiddleware.php:64)

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue!!!

It took a lot of time to fix it, but finally the solution was really simple.

It was just because of the .env cache. So I just cleared the cache and restart my server.

Now, it works.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: Cache was also a problem to me, thanks for the solution